# Problemas ao usar Heredocs

Tags: php

```
return
    <<< EOT
        <input type="text" name="questao{$this->numQuestao}" value="<?php echo $questao{$this->numQuestao}?>"/>

EOT;
```

Eu precisava printar isso no meu arquivo `html`:  `<?php echo $questao{$this->numQuestao}?>` com o `$`, porém está dando este erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

Se eu fizesse com aspas, funcionaria:

```
return
'value="<?php echo $questao'.$this->numQuestao.'">';
```

Comment: vc quer que seja "printado" o código php, certo?

Comment: Insere aspas duplas no início da expressão _heredoc_, para que fique assim : `<<<'EOT'`.

Comment: a tag de fechamento `EOT;` **não** pode ter nenhum caractere antes na mesma linha, incluindo espaços e tabulações

Answer (score 2):

Erro do heredocs, de acordo com a [documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php), ocorre quando a existem caracteres na mesma linha do identificador de fechamento

> É muito importante verificar que a linha do identificador de
>   fechamento não contenha nenhum outro caracter, exceto, possivelmente
>   um ponto e vírgula (;). O que significa que o identificador não pode
>   ser indentado, e que não pode haver nenhum espaço ou tabulações antes
>   ou depois do ponto e vírgula.

Então se você juntar o `EOT;` a esqueda da página, deveria funcionar.

No seu caso, acho que não precisa usar um heredocs, basta realizar a concatenação de strings

```
<?php 

$campo = 'teste';

return "<input type='text' name='". $teste."'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu HEREDOC tem um espaço depois do `<<<`.  Também outro problema que ocorre é achar que depois do `<<<EOT` podemos usar espaços.

Geralmente, depois da declaração `<<<EOT` vem uma quebra de linha, sendo a string escrita logo abaixo.

Assim:

```
    $x = <<<EOT
minha string de
teste
EOT;
   var_dump($x);
```

Saída:

```
string(21) "minha string de
teste"
```

Lembrando que, se você tabificar essa string, o tamanho do tab será considerado.

Veja de novo:

```
    $x = <<<EOT
    minha string de
    teste
EOT;
    var_dump($x);
```

Saída:

```
string(29) "    minha string de
    teste"
```

Note que o `EOT;` no final, não pode ser tabificado. Ele tem não pode ter espaços antes.