# Trechos repetitivos de HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Como atribuir blocos (ou trechos redundantes) de HTML a uma variável para poupar linhas e simplificar o uso? Imaginem várias DIV ou CÉLULAS de TABELA que são praticamente idênticas em 90%. Como salvar um trecho de HTML e recuperá-lo só por menção de sua variável?

Comment: Coloque o html dentro de um arquivo PHP e faça o include, que ele irá imprimir tudo que estiver nele

Comment: Poderia me dar um pequeno exemplo ou link? Sou novata em programação WEB. Faz muito sentido o que vc recomenda, mas um pequeno exemplo seria melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, esta resposta é uma discordância sobre a API da [resposta do @Sveen](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286822/64969). A ideia é a mesma, só que eu não gosto dessa [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/64969) via inclusão de código. Dificulta a manutenção e, na minha opinião, piora a legibilidade.

Então, minha solução? A mesma coisa, só que com função no lugar de inclusão. Não vou repetir o que o Sveen colocou na resposta dele pois seria desnecessário. A resposta dele realmente é boa e eu não teria muito a acrescentar.

Para começar, o jeitão do arquivo principal (`index.php`) seria assim:

```
<?php include_once "profileLayout.php" ?>
<html>
    <head> 
        <?PHP include "head.php"; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?PHP
            $usuarioLista = $banco->obterUsuarios();
            foreach($usuarioLista as $usuario){
               imprimeProfileLayout($usuario);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

E eu implementaria a função que imprime as coisas usando o chamado [`heredoc`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14241/64969) ([outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95486/64969)). Eis o arquivo `profileLayout.php` que define a função `imprimeProfileLayout`:

```
<?php
    function imprimeProfileLayout($usuario) {
    echo <<<EOT
<img src='{$usuario['foto_perfil']}'/>
<div class='nomeusuario'>{$usuario['nome']}</div>
<div class='controles'>
    <button>Seguir</button>
    <button>Adicionar aos Amigos</button>
    <button>Bloquear</button>
</div>
EOT;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Interessante essa abordagem... Obrigada.

Comment: @MayaFiuza por nada. Não se esqueça de navegar nas questões/respostas que linkei, muito conhecimento aguarda do outro lado do clique

Comment: Pelo que pude compreender (e aprender) até o presente momento é que, a melhor forma de recuperar linhas de HTML é através de sua prévia inserção em código PHP, correto?

Comment: Estava a buscar algo sobre a tag TEMPLATE cuja finalidade me pareceu coerente também com essa necessidade...

Comment: @MayaFiuza, sinceramente, sou amador demais em PHP para falar qual seria _**a**_ melhor maneira. Entendo de programação e nos 11 anos que mergulhei mais na área, incluindo faculdade e empregos, entendo que manutenção de código é algo importante. Eu fiz uma pesquisa cruzada usando ambas as tags [tag:template] e [tag:php], parece que tem coisas mais promissoras. Se você tiver curiosidade de ler minhas respostas, verá que eu costumo reinventar a roda, em diversas situações. Eu posso não saber qual _**a**_ melhor solução, mas consigo me virar com [XGH](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164124/64969)

Comment: Eu tenho lido, em verdade, a criatividade me é mais interessante por descortinar possibilidades. Valeu...

Answer (score 2):

Coloque o html dentro de um arquivo PHP e faça o include, que ele irá imprimir tudo que estiver nele. Exemplo básico de listagem de usuários:

**profileLayout.php (para realizar include)**

```
<img src='<?= $usuario['foto_perfil'] ?>'/>
<div class='nomeusuario'> <?= $usuario['nome'] ?> </div>
<div class='controles'>
    <button>Seguir</button>
    <button>Adicionar aos Amigos</button>
    <button>Bloquear</button>
</div>
```

**head.php (para realizar include)**

```
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

**index.php (origem)**

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <?PHP include "head.php"; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?PHP
            $usuarioLista = $banco->obterUsuarios();
            foreach($usuarioLista as $usuario){
               include "profileLayout.php";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Nese caso você poderia reutilizar o arquivo head para criar uma lista de arquivos javascript e folha de estilos em outras páginas do seu sistema. O mesmo para profileLayout.php que poderia te fornecer um html padrão para exibir cartões sobre os usuários. Dessa forma você não precisaria reescrever o mesmo código várias vezes.

Mas lembre-se que no resultado final, sempre haverá divs repetidas no HTML. Assim como uma imagem (produto final), você não tira os pixeis por serem repetidos.

Comment: Essa solução não me agrada, mas é boa. Gosto é gosto, certo? Não gosto de fazer a comunicação entre módulos através de variáveis implícitas (no caso foi o vetor associativo `$usuario`). Eu ainda faria o processamento no cliente, enviando um JSON do servidor para o cliente de modo que o servidor não precisasse se preocupar em como ficaria o layout.

Comment: Eu não botei muita coisa, pois não quero sobrecarregar quem ta começando a programar agora. Eu uso JSON também, inclusive para atualizar componentes do HTML, é muito legal. Mas seria diversas partes que deveriam ser explicadas.

Comment: Mas poderia ter feito uma função que fizesse a apresentação. Seria mais "_clean_". Controlar fluxo de código através de importações assim exige maturidade para que fique estável quando o projeto cresce.

Comment: Enfim, sou muito chato, criterioso e crítico. Mesmo discordando de detalhes da resposta (importação de arquivos em um laço), votei positivo e votaria positivo novamente caso a situação assim pedisse.

Comment: Em um arquivo .PHP (cadastro de produtos) que estou estudando, o trecho abaixo repete-se no mínimo 10x no mesmo arquivo, em locais diferentes e muda apenas algumas strings... 

 echo'
  <img src="../assets/img/correctofull.png" class="center-all-contens">
  <br>
  <h3>O produto foi adicionado a loja com êxito!</h3>
  <p class="lead text-cente">
    A página se redirecionará automaticamente. Caso contrário clique no botão VOLTAR.<br><br>
    <a href="../configAdmin.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">VOLTAR ao cadastro</a>
  </p>';

OBS: ainda não aprendi como formatar code aqui...

Comment: No comentário não dá para formatar, mas você pode ir tentando codificar, e se encontrar problemas é só criar uma nova pergunta. Veja que não é mais preciso usar echo imprimindo string com html, você pode usar o próprio HTML.

Comment: Obrigada pela paciência... É meu primeiro post! :^)